# Maybe a bug of matplotlib/seaborn axis range?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

```
ax=sns.relplot(data=price_quantity, x='Net price', y='Delivery quantity', 
hue='MG 5', height=10, aspect=.8)
plt.xlabel('Unit Price')
plt.ylabel('Delivery Quantity')
plt.title('Net Price-Delivery Quantity\n(RMB,Unit)')

plt.ylim(0, 500)
plt.xlim(0, 1000)
```

[image]

I was confused by this error! It was runnable last time and I cannot change the y range now. Once I removed the plt.ylim, then everything is fine. I have checked all details but cannot find a solution. I cannot change the y range for any figures now in python....However the xlimit works fine, very weired...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somewhere in the code you do not show here you have written something like `plt.ylim = (0,1)`. From this point on, `plt.ylim` is not a function any more, but a tuple.

Because you have overwritten the `ylim` function of pyplot, you need to restart your IPython (kernel).

Comment: I tried and you are right! I mistyped the function for another plot...You really saved my ass! Thank you.